# PostgreSQL copy 0?

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

I have written a simple batch script which loops a directory and echoes some details about each file.When I view its results in the CMD terminal or output it to some file, I can view the results as expected.

The problem comes with PostgreSQL: when I try to import its results into a table, executing the following command:

```
copy schema.table(field) from program 'C:\\...\\my_bat.bat' with CSV header delimiter E'\t';
```

It imports 0 results, whereas if I run the same command pointing to a similar batch file in another directory, it works as expected.

What's going on? I am using windows.

Update: I have tried running the copy command calling program again on another batch script and this time, only a part of the string output is being imported.

Comment: Try to replace those doubled backslashes with a single one in the file name. A backslash does not need to be escaped in SQL. Also: does the batch file exist on the **server** where Postgres is running?

Comment: Tried replacing the backslashes as instructed but did not change anything. Yes, the batch file does exist on PostgreSQL's server.

Comment: What's the content of `my_bat.bat`?

Answer (score 2):

The service user `postgres` needs sufficient permissions to run the program.

I remember that it was hard to change settings for that account on windows XP, I have not tried on more recent windows - service users are hidden by most GUI tools.